# WFS Layer Freezing QGIS Bonn 3.2.2

Tags: qgis, wfs, import

When adding a WFS layer to a project using Qgis Bonn 3.2.2, Qgis freezes up and will not come back to life.  I have re-added my WFS server and no changes.  WMS services seem to be working fine. Please let me know if there is any other info that may help in this matter.  I know this seems a little light on info.  Any help would be great.  I upgraded from Qgis 2.18 before 3.2.2 and all worked well.
[image]

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Do you get an error message or crash report? Check [if this bug has already been reported](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=wfs+layer+crash&scope=&all_words=&all_words=1&titles_only=&issues=1&commit=Submit), and make a bug report if not.

Comment: How big is the WFS response (you can check in a browser), you may find it's a disk cache issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but [upgrading](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) to QGIS 3.6.0 Noosa fixed it.